# Undefined index: docs (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sep-api/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Tags: json, laravel, api, http

**Hello I want to return a json value in a view from an api,
I am using GuzzleHttp,
but I have the following error**

Undefined index: docs (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sep-api/resources/views/home.blade.php)

THAT'S MY JSON

```
{
"responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 0,
"params": {
"fl": "*,score",
"q": "8092316",
"wt": "json"
}
},
"response": {
"numFound": 1,
"start": 0,
"maxScore": 5.1922903,
"docs": [
{
"nombre": "GUADALUPE",
"id": "8092316|C1",
"numCedula": "8092316",
"titulo": "LICENCIATURA EN CONTADURÍA",
"genero": "2",
"institucion": "UNIVERSIDAD VERACRUZANA",
"materno": "LUIS",
"anioRegistro": 2013,
"tipo": "C1",
"paterno": "LUIS",
"timestamp": "2020-09-02T06:20:01.7Z",
"score": 5.1922903
}
]
}
}
```

THAT'S MY CONTROLLER

```
public function index($cedulas)
{


    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://search.sep.gob.mx',
        'timeout' => 300,
        'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json',
        'Accept: application/vnd.api+json',
    ]);



    $response = $client->request('GET', "http://search.sep.gob.mx/solr/cedulasCore/select?fl=%2A%2Cscore&q={$cedulas}&wt=json");


         


        $posts = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);


    return view('home', compact('posts'));
```

**THAT'S MY VIEW**

```
    @foreach($posts['docs'] as $post)
 <h1>name: {{$post['nombre']}}</h1>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

as `doc` is inside `response` key in json (as u mentioned)

```php
@foreach($posts['response']['docs'] as $post)
    <h1>name: {{$post['nombre']}}</h1>
@endforeach
```

---

or

```php
$response = $client->request('GET', "http://search.sep.gob.mx/solr/cedulasCore/select?fl=%2A%2Cscore&q={$cedulas}&wt=json");

 $responseData = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);
 $posts = $responseData['response'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me !!

Comment: @luislalohdz it is solved your problem so please mark this answer so others can get benefit thanks